# How to access function from another swift file which access some variables - ios

Tags: ios, swift, null, viewcontroller

I have two swift files MenuViewController.swift and ViewController.swift

I got nil exception at the following function from ViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var webSiteView: UIWebView!

func LoadWebview(webURL: String) {
   let url = NSURL(string: webURL)
   let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
   webSiteView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest) 
}
```

I accessed the function using the following code from MenuViewController.swift

```
ViewController().LoadWebview(webURL: "http://www.google.com")
```

I got error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value as the attached screenshot

Error Screenshot -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLMGk.png)

Comment: Your ViewController should at least call viewDidLoad() before you can call the LoadWebview function. Also then you need to get the actual loaded instance of that controller and not a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a common mistake.

The default initializer `ViewController()` creates a brand new instance of the view controller which is **not** the instance in the storyboard.

Therefore the outlets are not connected and the code crashes.

And even if the new instance was the instance in the storyboard you can't use this syntax because the outlets are not connected anyway until the associated view has been loaded and `viewDidLoad` is called.

In your case you have to get the actual reference to the controller in the storyboard, either with an outlet, callback closure, protocol / delegate or pass the data in a segue.